# I/O operation on closed file?

Tags: python, list

Can you help me with this problem please? I am stuck with it, I don't understand where the problem is, I think its a problem of indentation, but I dont know exactly where:

There is the problem code:

```
while indexG<len(files):
    with open(files[indexG], 'r') as f:
        #
        statList = f.readlines()
        statList = [x.strip() for x in statList]
        for line in statList:
            if (re.search("=", str(line))):
                if (re.search('#IND', str(line))):
                    print("ERREUR")
                else:
                    result = re.findall("=\s*?(\d+\.\d+|\d+)", str(line))
                    print( result[0])
                    final_result.extend(result)
```

That is the error I get:

```
    File "C:/Users/skehal/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/testfloat.py", line 40, in <module>
        print("ERREUR")
    ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: Maybe the file is not opened properly?

Comment: i dont see how it can't be opened properly :/

Comment: What is on line 40? If it's `print("ERREUR")` then maybe the standard output is closed (IDE?).